# Selecting menu items using location.pathname + location.search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I ma using Javascript function to select menu items:

```
function selectActiveMenuItem() {
        var path = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash;
        var links = null;

        links = $("a[href='" + path + "']");

        links.parents("li").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('current').closest('li').addClass('current');
        });
    }
```

It is working strange - it doesn't work from the start when homepage is loaded. Homepage link in menu is not selected. I have to click on menu item (homepage or some other) and then it load page once again and right menu item is selected.

Previously I was using only:  `var path = location.pathname;` without `location.search` and then it was working fine from the begining. But now my links are more complicated - they look for example like that: `http://localhost//MainApp/User/Order.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=NMO` and other one is `http://localhost//MainApp/User/Order.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO`. So I have to use `location.pathname + location.search` to make my function work.

Also I tried using `var path = location.href.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '');` but the effect was the same as with `var path = location.pathname + location.search;`- homepage was not selected in menu when page loaded.

**The question:** How to make homepage selected in menu when page is loaded?

Comment: What does `path` contain and what is the link of your "home" button?

Comment: path contains: `/App/User/UserPage.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1` and home button has link: `<a href="/App/User/UserPage.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1">
                    User Page
                </a>`

Comment: But that works, doesn't it? I wanted to know what are the values when it does *not* work.

Comment: I checked it with alerts and indeed they differ - link has extra `&from=user` at the end. Thanks for this comment, now I know where is a problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add checking home link. Now function works and it looks like that:

```
function selectActiveMenuItem() {
        var path = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash;
        var createhomelink = null;
        var homepath = null;
        var links = null;
        createhomelink = path + "&from=user";
        homepath = document.getElementById("home").href.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '');

        if (createhomelink == homepath) {
            path = createhomelink;
        }

        links = $("a[href='" + path + "']");

        links.parents("li").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('current').closest('li').addClass('current');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the `[href^= ... ]` syntax to ignore the hash and query?

```
function selectActiveMenuItem() {
    $('a[href=^' + location.pathname + ']').parents('li').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('current').closest('li').addClass('current');
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't use it because some of my links differ only by endings. And this function ignore endings. I have added example of my links to question.